# Align all text in bullet

Tags: spacing, bullets

How do I remove the spacing before the first line of text in each bullet?

```
     \documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}


\cfoot{{\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont\footnotesize{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}}}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{blue}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{ #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
    \setlength{\itemindent}{-1em}\vspace{-1pt}\item[]
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  CV STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING-----------------
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
  {\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont{\textcolor{blue}{\Large \textbf{Mousumi Das}}}} & \includegraphics[width=5cm, height=2cm]{logocd (3).png} \\
\end{tabular*}
Morrisville, NC


%--------PROGRAMMING SKILLS------------
\section {\textcolor{blue}{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont\Large{\textbf{Qualification Summary}}}}
 \resumeSubHeadingListStart
 \resumeSubItem{}{
     {Statistical Programmer with 6+ years of experience in CRO environments supporting biopharmaceutical clients.}
     }
 \resumeSubItem{}{
     {Extensive experience producing safety and efficacy Tables, Figures, Listings (TFL) as per statistical analysis plan (SAP) and mock shells.}
    }
 \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
\vspace{-8px}
```

Comment: Please provide a full example. Additionally is all that code really necessary for the problem you have?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very complex. For the problem in question, I simply defined a custom `SubHeadingList`environment, based on `itemize` with the relevant parameters.

*Unrelated*:  `hyperref` should be loaded as the last package, with very few exceptions (most notably `cleveref`). Load `xcolor` rather then `color`. The `usenames` option is obsolete, as it has been the default for quite a few years. It is unnecessary to load palatino for the footer since it is loaded for the whole document.

```
 \documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\cfoot{{\footnotesize{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}}}


\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{blue}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{ #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
    \setlength{\itemindent}{-1em}\vspace{-1pt}\item[]
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

%-------------------------------------------

\newlist{SubHeadingList}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[SubHeadingList]{label =\textbullet, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, after=\vspace{-5pt}}
%%%%%% CV STARTS HERE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING-----------------
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
  {\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont{\textcolor{blue}{\Large \textbf{Mousumi Das}}}} & \includegraphics[width=4cm]{pepe-le-pew2} \\
\end{tabular*}
Morrisville, NC


%--------PROGRAMMING SKILLS------------
\section {\textcolor{blue}{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont\Large{\textbf{Qualification Summary}}}}
 \begin{SubHeadingList}
\item Statistical Programmer with 6+ years of experience in CRO environments supporting biopharmaceutical clients.

 \item
     Extensive experience producing safety and efficacy Tables, Figures, Listings (TFL) as per statistical analysis plan (SAP) and mock shells.

 \end{SubHeadingList}
\vspace{-8px}

\end{document}
```

[image]